# how can I get google analytics data using http request?

Tags: google-analytics

how can I get google analytics data using http request ?

I am using http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ to get my ga datas , there is a button to get the ga link, I open the generated link in new window , it return an error info.

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

how can I send token to google togater with the link ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to authorize your request with OAuth 2.0. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization) on how to create refresh and access tokens. Then pass the access token either with the `Authorization` header

```
Authorization: Bearer 1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg
```

or as query parameter `access_token`:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg&...
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the Analytics Reporting API

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/